# Verilog: assigning value to reg

Tags: verilog

I have this very beginner question about Verilog and I would love some help, please.

Below you can see the code for a simple counter which has:

1. input: single clock signal, connected to the clock
2. input: reset signal, which is connected to a physical button
3. output: the counter output
4. output: led equal to reset input

The odd behaviour is that when the reset signal is high, the counter doesn't reset to zero.
On the board I can see the led switching  on and off when I press the button so reset is true, but the if instruction `internal_counter <= 0;` is not executed (?)

I'm using Quartus Prime II Lite with a DE-10 Nano Terasic Board

Any suggestion, please? Thanks!

```
//Single clock input and a 32bit output port
    //reset will zero the internal_counter 
    module simple_counter (
                                    CLOCK_50,
                                    counter_out,
                                    reset,
                                    led
                                );          

    input CLOCK_50 ;
    input reset ;
    output led;
    output [31:0] counter_out;
    reg [31:0] counter_out;
    reg [31:0] internal_counter;
    reg led;

    always @ (posedge CLOCK_50) // on positive clock edge
        begin
            if (reset)
                        internal_counter <= 0;

            led <= reset;
            internal_counter <= internal_counter + 1;
            counter_out <= internal_counter;// increment counter
        end

    endmodule // end of module counter
```

Comment: Just add else block after ` led <= reset ; ` and ur code will work fine, but in the else block modify the led value also

Comment: Which assignment to `internal_counter` do you thing is working?

Comment: Hi @RAMAKRISHNAMEDA, thank you for your suggestion. I implemented it and worked, like suggested by Seaotter211 and Oldfart. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @TomServo, that's the question I should have asked myself earlier on :)  Clearly it was the last one. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because you make two assignments to `internal_counter`. This is allowed but the rule is that *the last assignment "wins"*.

So let's step through the code when the reset is active:

```
if (reset)   
  internal_counter <= 0;
```

This makes that the `internal_counter` is reset (set to zero).
But later we get another assignment:

```
internal_counter <= internal_counter + 1;
```

As this one is later/behind the previous assignment it "wins". There is **no** condition here so this **always** replaces the previous `if ...`. With that the `if...` code becomes superfluous. It is never executed and the synthesis tool will remove any logic for that.

As others have pointed out: you need an `else` section. It is good practice to reset all the variables in the reset section:

```
always @ (posedge CLOCK_50) // on positive clock edge
begin
   if (reset)
   begin
      internal_counter <= 0;
      led <= 1'b1; 
      counter_out  <= 0;
   end // reset section
   else
   begin // clocked section
      internal_counter <= internal_counter + 1;
      led <= 1'b0; 
      counter_out <= internal_counter; 
   end
end // clocked section
```

Now we get some general remarks:

I suggest you switch to ANSI port definitions. It is easier as you keep everything together. If you need to change e.g. the width of `counter_out` you can do that in one place:

```
module simple_counter (
    input      CLOCK_50 ,
    input      reset ,
    output reg led,
    output reg [31:0] counter_out  
   );
```

Your `led` is a bit weird. It is high on reset, low otherwise. I assume you did this for debugging.

The`counter_out` is always one value behind the internal_counter. Is this what you want? It also costs you 32 extra registers. I would expect to do without the internal counter and use the counter_out direct:

```
always @ (posedge CLOCK_50) // on positive clock edge
begin
   if (reset)
   begin
      led <= 1'b1; 
      counter_out  <= 0;
   end // reset section
   else
   begin // clocked section
      led <= 1'b0; 
      counter_out <= counter_out + 1; 
   end
end // clocked section
```

Comment: Hi Oldfart, thank you for your reply. I much appreciate the time you took to explain the "last assignment wins" rule and the benefits of ANSI port definitions. 
You were right, the led variable was there for debugging, well spotted!
And for the intenal_counter: again, I should take it away. 
Thanks again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why your code does not work. I work with VHDL nowadays.
However, I would write it like this:

```
module simple_counter (CLOCK_50, reset, led, counter_out);          

    input CLOCK_50 ;
    input reset ;
    output led;
    output [31:0] counter_out;

    reg [31:0] internal_counter;

    always @ (posedge CLOCK_50)
      begin
         if (reset)
            internal_counter <= 0;
         else
            internal_counter <= internal_counter + 1;

         led <= reset;
         counter_out <= internal_counter;
      end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you very much Seaotter211, it looks better the way you structured it! I will implement your suggestion and let you know the result. 
Cheers again!

Comment: Great, it worked. I did not know about the rule "last assignment wins", and just adding an else statement did the trick. Thank you SeaOtter211!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some more improvements using Verilog-2001 variant, and your code isn't working because during reset you are assigning `internal_counter <= 0` and `internal_counter <= internal_counter + 1'b1`, so usually when u are modifying like this tools will take the second assignment in reset condition so it wont result into assigning to 0.. I have added reset_synchronizer in your code so the glithces in on/off of led u may not encounter with this implementation (based on some switches u used it may not work also).

```
module simple_counter (
   input             clock_50
  ,input             reset
  ,output reg        led
  ,output reg [31:0] counter_out
);

reg [9:0] reset_sync = 10'h3_FF;
reg       system_reset = 1'b1 ;

// to remove glitches in PUSH Button reset
always@(posedge clock_50) begin
      reset_sync   <= #1  {reset_sync[8:0],reset};
      system_reset <= #1 &(reset_sync[9:2]);
end

always@(posedge clock_50)begin
  if (system_reset) begin
        led         <= #1 1'b0;
        counter_out <= #1 32'b0;
  end else begin
        led         <= #1 1'b1;
        counter_out <= #1 counter_out + 1'b1 ;// increment counter
  end
 end

endmodule
```

Comment: You don't need 10 registers to sync, 2 is enough. Your reset sync is flawed as it has no initial value which leads to the problem: how do you reset the reset circuit? There are solutions for that but they are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks oldfart, i modified the code , i forgot to do **reduce and** operation ,thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thank you @RAMAKRISHNAMEDA, interesting solution for the reset_sync. Much appreciated :)